# how do we increase the maximum fetch size for kafka spout

Tags: apache-kafka

I am using kafkaspout, I would like to increase the maximum fetch size in KafkaSpout. Can you please share your thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust message fetch size in one of two ways, either by by changing the Kafka spout's configuration programmatically or by altering the configuration of the Kafka server directly.

To change the spout's configuration, the [Kafka spout documentation](https://github.com/apache/storm/tree/master/external/storm-kafka) tells us to set the the spout's config's fetchSizeBytes variable. Assuming this is being done doing this in java:

```
spoutConfig.fetchSizeBytes = maximumFetchSize;
```

The other option, i.e. to adjust the Kafka configuration, first find Kafka's `server.properties`, then change that configuration, finally restart the Kafka server.

The Kafka configuration will most likely be in the `config` directory off of the Kafka's home directory. Adjust the [appropriate configuration value](https://kafka.apache.org/08/configuration.html) by adding something similar to the following line to `server.properties`:

```
message.max.bytes=some_new_integer_value
```

Then restart the Kafka process. Best practice will be to repeat this change on all hosts in the cluster.

Comment: Thanks. Can we increase the fetch.message.max.bytes in the server.properties file in the conf of kafka. Please suggest.

Comment: Short answer: Yes. I've expanded the answer to include this option.

Comment: Thanks a lot. How the fetchSizeBytes  would be used in KafkaSpout for checking?

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. Could you restate that in a different way?